# Отказ в доступе во время установки yggdrasil на fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

https://yggdrasil-network.github.io/installation-linux-rpm.html
Действовал по написанной инструкции, но когда дошел до создания репозитория пришла ошибка:
/etc/yum.repos.d/yggdrasil.repo: отказано в доступе

Comment: Про `sudo` не забыл?

Answer (score 0):

Выполни команду, написав sudo переде ней и введя пароль.